# Not able to insert data using MySqli Insert Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have following php code to insert data into mysql and at the same time send an email. The email is going but data is not getting inserted into the database.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name"); 


$cName = $_POST['cName'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$address = $_POST['address'];


$query = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO registration(CompanyName,Contact,Address) VALUES('$cName','$contact','$address')");

$message = "Registration Details";
$message .= $cName;
$message .= $contact;
$message .= $address;

mail("example@domain.com", "Registration Email", $message);


mysql_close($connection);


?>
```

The catch is this code works fine in my local machine using localhost. The problem arises when i put it online. The email is going but data is not getting inserted. Please help me..

Comment: Please debug $connection whether it return resource id or not..

Comment: May not be causing the problem but at the end you're using `mysql_close()` whereas it should be `mysqli_close()`.

Comment: Make sure $contact and $cName do not have ' in them. 
E.g. Contact: "Firstname O'Connell".
 $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $contact);

Comment: [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) would have told you about the error. Also add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Thanks guys. mysql_close() was the problem. I used mysqli_close and now it is working. Thans guys for the insight. I love stackoverflow.com. :p

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please fix this :)

Answer (score -1):

Just Modify your code to debug the error. Here is your full code in proper way.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name"); 

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO registration(CompanyName,Contact,Address) VALUES('".$cName."','".$contact."','".$address."')"))
{
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

$message = "Registration Details";
$message .= $cName;
$message .= $contact;
$message .= $address;

mail("example@domain.com", "Registration Email", $message);

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```